# Nexus hosted Nuget repository returns wrong version numbers to Nuget client

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nexus

I'm responsible for setting up a hosted nuget repository using nexus.  I'm currently prototyping on my local machine and I'm seeing a weird issue.

The issue manifests itself in the Visual Studio 2015 nuget client - basically the version numbers for the packages I've pushed are all wrong.  The display seems to default to the highest version number of any package in the repository.
Furthermore, when you select a package on the left, the detail panel on the right has a version dropdown - and that is populated with *all version numbers of all packages in the repository*.

For example, I have 3 packages in my nexus/nuget repo:

```
package1/v1.0.0 
package2/v2.1.0
package3/v3.0.0
```

No other versions of these packages are in there.

The Nuget Client browse tab will display, incorrectly:

package1 v3.0.0

package2 v3.0.0

package3 v3.0.0

Then if you view the details for package1, the version dropdown will display

- Latest Stable 3.0.0
- 3.0.0
- 2.1.0
- 1.0.0

Since only v1.0.0 of package1 actually exists in the repo, selecting any other version will cause the package installer to bomb out (which makes sense).

I've isolated this problem to the server as opposed to the nuget client.  For example, on the package management command line:

```
Find-Package package -AllVersions |select Id, Versions
```

I get returned:

```
Id        Versions
--        --------    
package1  {3.0.0, 2.1.0, 1.0.0}
pacakge2  {3.0.0, 2.1.0, 1.0.0}
package3  {3.0.0, 2.1.0, 1.0.0}
```

Which tells me clearly that the repository is feeding the client bad data rather than the client mangling the data itself.

**Has anyone experienced this issue and know how to resolve it?**

**Versions of software I'm using**

- List Nexus OSS v3.2.0 (Free version)
- Nuget packages pushed with v3.5.0
- Nuget client in visual studio v3.4.0

Comment: Are those packages custom? some of these packages may have been available with the same name, but different content and version numbering on nuget.org. Could you please try to clear the NuGet cache and update the NuGet client in visual studio to v3.5.0, then restart visual studio? If this issue is still persist, would you mind sharing us a screenshot of this issue on NuGet client in visual studio?

Comment: Yes, the packages are custom and proprietary, unfortunately, so I can't share a screen shot.  I successfully cleared the nuget cache and that didn't fix the issue.  It seems there is no vs nuget client v3.5.0.  just the nuget CLI version goes that high.  So i've got the most current versions of everything.

Comment: I just want to reiterate that i'm 95% certain this is not a nuget/visual studio issue, but rather a Nexus issue - or at least the way I have configured nexus.   Instructions i followed are here: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/nuget.html#nuget-introduction

Comment: I stand corrected, at least partially - upgrading from the visual studio nuget client v3.4.0 to v3.4.4 (current highest) seems to have fixed the issue.  Leo, if you convert your comment to an answer I will give you credit.

Comment: I'm glad you have solved your problem, I have converted my comment to an answer, you can credit it when you free. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is more relate to the old version NuGet, you can try to update your Nuget client in Visual studio. The current highest stable version is V3.4.4. If you have interest to test the NuGet beta version. You can get it at: [NuGet Distributions](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html).

> The NuGet Beta Channel for the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2015 gives you access to high-quality builds that are close to completion. We use this channel to gather feedback on our near-final builds, and it's recommended for developers who want to try out new features and those who are experiencing blocking issues and need early access to updated builds before RTM.